# How to use $index in isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have made a custom directive to have set a duration(days hours minutes) in input box. It is more like Expected time Taken. Now it is work as it should.
To set the time you need to pass JSON with keys like Days, hours and minutes.

I have used Isolated scope so making copies of it on any one page is working too. but in this scenario you need to define that JSON for every copy.Now this is great if we know how many copies needed to be made.

But Now I want to make copies but variables are dynamic so I am trying to use $index from ng-repeat, but I am not getting $index value in my directive instead it comes as undefined.

code:

Directive

```
angular.module('estimated',['ui.bootstrap'])

.directive('estimated',[function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: 'element',
        templateUrl: 'counter.html',
        scope:{
            duration:'=time',
            visible:'=show'
        },
        controller: function($scope){

            },
        link:function(scope, element, attrs,ctrl) {

            var input = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByTagName('input'));

            input.attr('class','form-control');

            var setduration = function(){
                scope.duration;
                durationformatfunc();
            }

            var durationformatfunc = function(){
                scope.durationformat = ' ';
                if(scope.visible.indexOf('days') >= 0){
                    scope.durationformat = scope.duration.days + "d ";
                }
                if(scope.visible.indexOf('hours') >= 0){
                    scope.durationformat += scope.duration.hours + "h ";
                }

                if(scope.visible.indexOf('minutes') >= 0){
                    scope.durationformat += scope.duration.minutes + "m";
                }
                input.attr('value',scope.durationformat);
            }

            scope.preventDefault = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            };

            var updateduration = function(){
                durationformatfunc();
            }

            setduration(); // call first time
            scope.incrementDays = function(){
                if(scope.duration.days < 30){
                    scope.duration.days = scope.duration.days + 1;
                }
                else
                    scope.duration.hours = 0; 
            }
            scope.incrementHours = function(){
                if(scope.duration.hours < 23){
                    scope.duration.hours = scope.duration.hours + 1;
                }
                else{
                    scope.duration.hours = 0; 
                    scope.incrementDays();
                }
            }
            scope.incrementMinutes = function(){
                if(scope.duration.minutes < 55)
                    scope.duration.minutes = scope.duration.minutes + 5;
                else{
                    scope.duration.minutes = 0; 
                    scope.incrementHours();
                }
            }
            scope.decrementDays = function(){
                if(scope.duration.days == 1)
                    scope.duration.days = 30; 
                else
                    scope.duration.days = scope.duration.days - 1;
            }
            scope.decrementHours = function(){
                if(scope.duration.hours == 0){
                    scope.duration.hours = 23;
                    scope.decrementDays();
                }
                else
                    scope.duration.hours = scope.duration.hours - 1;
            }
            scope.decrementMinutes = function(){
                if(scope.duration.minutes == 0)
                    {
                    scope.duration.minutes = 55;
                    scope.decrementHours(); 
                    }
                else
                    scope.duration.minutes = scope.duration.minutes - 5;
            }

            scope.$watch('duration',function(newValue, oldValue) {
                      updateduration();
                  },true);

        }
      }
}])
```

html that works

```
<input type="text" value="" show="['days','hours','minutes']"  time="count" estimated>
```

html that I want to work

```
<input type="text" value="" show="['days','hours','minutes']" ng-repeat="x in counts track by $index"  time="count{{$index}}" estimated>
```

count defined in controller

```
$scope.count ={
                        days:0,
                        hours:02,
                        minutes:50
                    }
```

Counter.html / Template

```
<div class="dropdown durationdiv" dropdown>
  <div class="dropdown-toggle input-group" ng-class="" dropdown-toggle>
   <div class="input-group">
    <div class="time-input" ng-transclude></div>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa-clock-o fa curp"></i>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="preventDefault($event)" dropdown-menu>

    <div ng-if="visible.indexOf('days') >= 0" class="days-col pull-left">
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="incrementDays()"><i class="fa-chevron-up fa curp"></i></a></div>
      <div class="days-val">{{ duration.days}}</div>
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="decrementDays()"><i class="fa-chevron-down fa curp"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="visible.indexOf('hours') >= 0" class="hours-col pull-left">
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="incrementHours()"><i class="fa-chevron-up fa curp"></i></a></div>
      <div class="hours-val">{{ duration.hours }}</div>
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="decrementHours()"><i class="fa-chevron-down fa curp"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="visible.indexOf('minutes') >= 0" class="minutes-col  pull-left">
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="incrementMinutes(e)"><i class="fa-chevron-up fa curp"></i></a></div>
      <div class="minutes-val">{{ duration.minutes }}</div>
      <div><a class="btn" ng-click="decrementMinutes()"><i class="fa-chevron-down fa curp"></i></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PLUNKER

http://plnkr.co/edit/I3scaAkYRaK19YIjpSMz?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys but I have resolved the issue. I changed a way to make dynamic variables..Instead of making independent variable now I am making array of variables and using $index as array index

html with delete button

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in counts track by $index" >
    <input type="text" value="" show="['days','hours','minutes']" time="count[$index]" estimated>
<a href="" ng-click="delcount($index)">delete</a>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.counts = [];
    $scope.copycount = function(){
        $scope.counts.push({
                            days:0,
                            hours:02,
                            minutes:50
                        });
$scope.delcount = function(i){
    $scope.counts.splice(i,1);
}

                    $scope.counts[0] = {
                        days:0,
                        hours:02,
                        minutes:50
                    };
```

add button

```
<button ng-click="copycount()">copy</button>
```

Delete button

```
<a href="" ng-click="delcount($index)">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Insted of this :

```
time="count{{$index}}"
```

Can you try something like this ?

```
time="count($index)"
```

**EDIT**

And in your directive :

```
scope:{
         duration:'&time',
         visible:'=show'
        },
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: no that does not work, It still says undefined, In my understanding {{}} this is to be used as I want evaluated value and not $index dynamic value. 

To evaluate angular expression we use {{}}

Comment: Can you try with my Edit ?

Comment: No its not working, anyway I have added the plunker, you can test in that

PLUNKER

http://plnkr.co/edit/I3scaAkYRaK19YIjpSMz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you are try to pass `object+$index like { days:0, hours:02, minutes:50 }1($index)` so this may give problem. Get index by separate. Change your code given below.

```
scope:{
            duration:'=time',
            visible:'=show',
            index:'=getIndex',    
      },

<input type="text" value="" show="['days','hours','minutes']" ng-repeat="x in counts track by $index" get-index="{{$index + 1}}"  time="count">
```

Comment: I can not do that, I just don't want $index but I want 2 way binding with parent scope variable that will be dynamic (count{{$index}} = count0)

Comment: sorry i forgot this. {{$index + 1}}. see my update answer. now you can get

Comment: still not right, I don't want $index value, instead I want to use $index to access dynamic variable, that is in sync with my isolated scope variable. 

count0 will be dynamically created, it can count or count40 in parent controller, I want that variable to be 2 way binded to isolated scope variable "duration" so when I change value of duration in my directive it is reflected on count{{$index}}

Comment: can you give plunkr link?

Comment: Just added plunker,

Comment: 99% for your requirement is not possible. Do different scenario.